# Block bots from accessing WordPress Search URLs with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using Wordpress with Algolia and I am currently logging up to 10,000 spam search queries per day which seem to come from Googlebot.

They look like this:

```
GET /de/%21/6/?s=+Wo+kaufen+viagra+in+wien%F0%9F%96%95%F0%9F%A4%AA%F0%9F%8E%96+www.ZavaMed.store+%F0%9F%8E%96%F0%9F%A4%AA%F0%9F%96%95+Kamagra+aus+indien+bestellen+Cialis+5mg+f%C3%BCr+die+frau+preis+im+ausland+bestellen+Viagra+150+mg+kaufen+ohne+rezept+billige HTTP/1.1" 200 33087 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.83 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" "MISS:(lb2-c28-2)" "not-in-cache" "-" "66.249.66.81" "0" "0" "1" 0.693 0.690 D=684513
```

I am blocking `/?s=` and `/search/` pages using `robots.txt` and I am using "noindex" on search result pages. But the spam search queries keep coming in.

What I am looking to do is to use htaccess to block googlebot's and bingbot's access to `/?s=` and `/search` pages but keep allowing their access to all other pages on the site.

Unfortunately, I'm not very good with `.htaccess` and regex and after 2-3 days of working on it, this is the best I could come up with:

```
# BEGIN SEARCH FORM PROTECTION
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ “https://example.com/?s=” [R=403,L]
# END SEARCH FORM PROTECTION
```

This stops the spam queries but also blocks Google (and Bing I assume) from accessing all other pages.

Here is the robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /cart/
Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /my-account/
Disallow: /search/
Disallow: /*?s=
Disallow: /*?orderby=price
Disallow: /*?orderby=price-desc
Disallow: /*?orderby=rating
Disallow: /*?orderby=popularity
Disallow: /*?orderby=date
Disallow: /*?filter
Disallow: /*add-to-cart=*
Allow: /wp-content/uploads/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

And here is the .htaccess

```
# BEGIN Search Form Protection
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s= [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search/
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
# End Search Form Protection

# BEGIN Imagify: webp file type
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType image/webp .webp
</IfModule>
# END Imagify: webp file type

# BEGIN WP Rocket v3.9.4
# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
# Force UTF-8 for a number of file formats
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddCharset UTF-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .xml
</IfModule>

# FileETag None is not enough for every server.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

# Since we’re sending far-future expires, we don’t need ETags for static content.
# developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
FileETag None

# Send CORS headers if browsers request them; enabled by default for images.
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# mod_headers, y u no match by Content-Type?!
<FilesMatch "\.(cur|gif|png|jpe?g|svgz?|ico|webp)$">
SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Allow access to web fonts from all domains.
<FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|tt[cf]|woff2?)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Powered-By "WP Rocket/3.9.4"
Header unset Pragma
Header append Cache-Control "public"
Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|js|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset Pragma
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Expires headers (for better cache control)
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                              "access plus 1 month"
    # cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest           "access plus 0 seconds"
    # Your document html
    ExpiresByType text/html                     "access plus 0 seconds"
    # Data
    ExpiresByType text/xml                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    # Feed
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml           "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml          "access plus 1 hour"
    # Favicon (cannot be renamed)
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                  "access plus 1 week"
    # Media: images, video, audio
    ExpiresByType image/gif                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/png                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                    "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                    "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                    "access plus 4 months"
    # HTC files  (css3pie)
    ExpiresByType text/x-component              "access plus 1 month"
    # Webfonts
    ExpiresByType font/ttf                      "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType font/otf                      "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType font/woff2                    "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
    # CSS and JavaScript
    ExpiresByType text/css                      "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript        "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# Gzip compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Active compression
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Force deflate for mangled headers
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
# Don’t compress images and other uncompressible content
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|rar|zip|exe|flv|mov|wma|mp3|avi|swf|mp?g|mp4|webm|webp|pdf)$ no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                  application/javascript \
                                  application/json \
                                  application/rss+xml \
                                  application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                  application/x-font-ttf \
                                  application/xhtml+xml \
                                  application/xml \
                                  font/opentype \
                                  image/svg+xml \
                                  image/x-icon \
                                  text/css \
                                  text/html \
                                  text/plain \
                                  text/x-component \
                                  text/xml
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# END WP Rocket

### BEGIN GTranslate config ###
RewriteRule ^(af|sq|am|ar|hy|az|eu|be|bn|bs|bg|ca|ceb|ny|zh-CN|zh-TW|co|hr|cs|da|nl|en|eo|et|tl|fi|fr|fy|gl|ka|de|el|gu|ht|ha|haw|iw|hi|hmn|hu|is|ig|id|ga|it|ja|jw|kn|kk|km|ko|ku|ky|lo|la|lv|lt|lb|mk|mg|ms|ml|mt|mi|mr|mn|my|ne|no|ps|fa|pl|pt|pa|ro|ru|sm|gd|sr|st|sn|sd|si|sk|sl|so|es|su|sw|sv|tg|ta|te|th|tr|uk|ur|uz|vi|cy|xh|yi|yo|zu)/(af|sq|am|ar|hy|az|eu|be|bn|bs|bg|ca|ceb|ny|zh-CN|zh-TW|co|hr|cs|da|nl|en|eo|et|tl|fi|fr|fy|gl|ka|de|el|gu|ht|ha|haw|iw|hi|hmn|hu|is|ig|id|ga|it|ja|jw|kn|kk|km|ko|ku|ky|lo|la|lv|lt|lb|mk|mg|ms|ml|mt|mi|mr|mn|my|ne|no|ps|fa|pl|pt|pa|ro|ru|sm|gd|sr|st|sn|sd|si|sk|sl|so|es|su|sw|sv|tg|ta|te|th|tr|uk|ur|uz|vi|cy|xh|yi|yo|zu)/(.*)$ /$1/$3 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(ar|zh-CN|nl|en|fr|de|it|ja|ko|pl|pt|ru|es|tr)/(.*)$ /wp-content/plugins/gtranslate/url_addon/gtranslate.php?glang=$1&gurl=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(af|sq|am|ar|hy|az|eu|be|bn|bs|bg|ca|ceb|ny|zh-CN|zh-TW|co|hr|cs|da|nl|en|eo|et|tl|fi|fr|fy|gl|ka|de|el|gu|ht|ha|haw|iw|hi|hmn|hu|is|ig|id|ga|it|ja|jw|kn|kk|km|ko|ku|ky|lo|la|lv|lt|lb|mk|mg|ms|ml|mt|mi|mr|mn|my|ne|no|ps|fa|pl|pt|pa|ro|ru|sm|gd|sr|st|sn|sd|si|sk|sl|so|es|su|sw|sv|tg|ta|te|th|tr|uk|ur|uz|vi|cy|xh|yi|yo|zu)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
### END GTranslate config ###

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
```

Comment: Please include the contents of your `robots.txt` file. Has your `robots.txt` file recently been updated? (It's "very unusual" for Googlebot to _ignore_ the `robots.txt` directives.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about _configuring_ wordpress, not _development_ (see [help/on-topic]). It fits better on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MrWhite Thank you for your replies. Editing original reply with robots.txt

Answer (score 0):

> I am blocking `/?s=` and `/search/` pages using `robots.txt`

It would be interesting to see your `robots.txt` file - it is "very unusual" for Googlebot to crawl pages that are correctly blocked in `robots.txt`. For example, to block the example URL stated, you would need to use the following directive:

```
Disallow: /*/?s=
```

(Not simply `/?s=`, as could be implied by your question.)

However, to completely block access to these URLs you would need to do something like the following near the *top* of your root `.htaccess` file (it must go *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s= [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search/
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The above will serve a 403 Forbidden for any URL that includes a query string that *starts* `s=` *or* where the URL-path *starts* `/search/`.

The `F` flag is shorthand for `R=403`. The `L` flag is not required.

The regex `^` is successful for every URL (at which point the preceding *conditions* are processed) and the `-` (hyphen) explicitly indicates no substitution (it is discarded anyway when specifying a 4xx response code).

(You were also using *curly* quotes in your directive to surround the *substitution* argument, which is syntactically invalid.)

Comment: Thank you for your time - I greatly appreciate it. I agree it is unusual for Googlebot to crawl pages that are blocked with robots.txt. We double-checked they are, indeed, blocked via Search Console. Sure enough, the page can't be crawled or fetched because it is "blocked by robots.txt". And yet, the queries go through.

I added the above in .htaccess (at the top of .htaccess) but they _still_ go through. Very strange.

Comment: @GeorgeF. "I added the above in .htaccess (at the top of .htaccess) but they still go through." - That would seem to be impossible given the example in the question, unless the directives are not being processed at all? (But you say your initial rule blocked everything?) Is the URL the same format? Where are you seeing that log entry? Is that from Apache's access log?

Comment: @GeorgeF. Could you also add your complete `.htaccess` file to the question with these directives in place? Thanks.

Comment: Certainly. Just added. Thank you!

Comment: This just crossed my mind. We are using a plugin to auto-translate the website. So we have subdirectories like example.com/de/

Could the subdirectories be where the requests are coming from and could that be why robots.txt isn't working as it is in the root or why the htaccess rules that your wrote don't seem to work in this case?

Comment: We found the reason Google "ignores" robots.txt is because the spammers link to these pages from another (external) page. Google crawls THAT page and follows the link. This indexes the page as well. Because due to robots.txt, Google can't see the "noindex" tag. That's their angle. We removed the disallow rules from robots.txt because the spam pages were getting indexed. And now hoping to find a way to forbid access with htaccess.